# Selenium: How to wait for DOM change?

Tags: selenium

My test needs to wait for server push update to delete a row from a table. How can I tell Selenium to wait until a change to the table DOM has occurred?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. You can either wait for an element to be present (or not present) using `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementSelectedBy(By.selector()))`
2. You can test if JQuery is finished on the page with `((Boolean)driver.executeScript("return jQuery.active == 0"))`